# Permissions to PHP session files

Tags: php, apache, file, session

I have a domain domain.com and subdomain sub.domain.com Those two domains have different ftp users (user1, user2) belonging to the same group (usergroup) on linux environment.  Finally I have the same PHP application that uses sessions on both domains (one is live and other is testing environment).

When I go to domain.com without going first to sub.domain.com, PHP session file is created in default folder /tmp/ with proper permissions 600 and user1:usergroup, when I access sub.domain.com without going first to domain.com, a file is created with permissions 600 and user2:usergroup.

All is great for all browsers but IE (please do not focus on this).  What I found out is that when I access sub.domain.com and then try domain.com PHP tries to read the same session file but has no permissions and page is loading indefinitely.  Changing ownership of the file to user1 makes domain.com work but prevents sub.domain.com from working.

How to make Apache or PHP create different files for sessions or make them accessible from both domains.

P.S.
Like I said for some weird reason this happens only for IE and the error message from PHP is:
Uncaught PHP Error: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/tmp/sess_t1..., O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in file xxx.php on line 46
on line on line 46 is session_start();

Thank you for any advice in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this same problem. It appears to be a problem with the way Apache returns session data for IE7 and IE8, but most likely because IE7 and IE8 have an improper way of announcing the domain they're requesting session data for.

Here's my scenario:

Running Apache 1.3 with two domains, each has their own account with their own users:

```
Domain: mycompany.com 
Session path: /tmp/
Webserver user: mycompanycom

Domain: support.mycompany.com 
Session path: /tmp/
Webserver user: nobody
```

Here is what happens during a normal visit with Firefox/Safari/Chrome:

1. I visit mycompany.com and session file is created in `/tmp/` owned by the user `mycompanycom`.
2. I then visit support.mycompany.com, and second session file is created in `/tmp/` owned by user `nobody`.
3. Apache doesn't get confused and the correct session files are returned

However, here's what happens during a visit with IE7 and IE8:

1. I visit mycompany.com and session file is created in `/tmp/` owned by the user `mycompanycom`.
2. I then visit support.mycompany.com and, instead of creating second session file in `/tmp/` owned by the user `nobody`, Apache tries to return the session file for mycompany.com.
3. The session file for mycompany.com is owned by the user `mycompanycom`, so the web server, running as user `nobody` cannot access it. Permission is denied.

The solution was, as others have suggested, to create a separate directory in `/tmp/` to separate the stored session data for support.mycompany.com:

```
mkdir /tmp/mycompany
chown nobody:nobody /tmp/mycompany
```

I then added the following to an `.htaccess` file in the root web directory for support.mycompany.com:

```
php_value session.save_path '/tmp/mycompany'
```

And finally, I removed any existing session data in `/tmp/` to ensure the new session path would get used immediately:

```
rm -f /tmp/sess_*
```

And that's it! Now IE7 and IE8 work properly.

I'm fairly certain this problem has to do with how IE7 and IE8 request session data from Apache. They probably first request session data for mycompany.com and THEN request session data for support.mycompany.com, even though the latter was the only doman entered in the address bar.

Comment: Really good explanation of the problem. I solved it by detecting the domain in PHP and changing session_save_path() accordingly.

Comment: That seems very odd as browsers can't request session data. Session data is always kept server-side. The only session-related communication between server and browser is the communication of the session ID, and this is done through cookies or URL parameters. And either way the browser itself is completely oblivious to which cookie/URL parameter is a session ID.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the best approach for your problem but you could try having PHP save session files in different directory for each domain.

Take a look on [session_save_path()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) documentation.

Keep in mind that you must set it BEFORE initializing the session.
Ideally, that should be one of the first things your script does.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be solving a problem.
I've set up session.save_path for subdomain to a different directory.

Comment: hmmm, actually something else is happening now. When I enter the site for the first time the session file gets created in new directory but when I close the browser and try to access it again it freezes again :(

Comment: Are you confident that the (current) freezing is coming from the session_start() call and not something else?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that IE is triggering the issue?

The browser does not have any direct access to the session files, only the PHP (HTTPD) process has access to the session files.

I do not see why one browser should give different error messages in the PHP log versus another.

I think you may be dealing with two separate issues.

Comment: I have Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, IE7 and IE8 standalone.  Everything works perfectly in all browsers except for both IE.  I know browser should not have any impact on session files, thats why I'm so clueless here.

Comment: I understand your frustration but I still can not see how browsers can influence the status of the sessions in the backend.

Something else is playing up.

Comment: A solution for your problem of sharing sessions may be to simply chmod to 660 as you said they belong to same group, they should be allowed to read/write each other's session files.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add this to the .htaccess file of each subdomain:

```
php_value session.save_path '/path/to/a/writeable/folder'
```

Then ensure that each subdomain has permission to write to its own folder.

Comment: +1 Carlos Lima gave a similar answer to you but I think your solution is much cleaner because I believe this to be an environment problem rather than a scripting problem.